# Remove item transition for window resize, but keep transition for filtering/showing/hiding items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-isotope

I would like to remove the transition on the isotope items when the window resizes (so that the items do not animate their position or size), but still maintain the scaling/opacity/position transitions that happen when filtering/hiding/showing items.

Using the following code, however:

```
$container.isotope({transitionDuration: 0});
```

Removes both the window resize transition and the hide/show transition.

How can I just remove the window resize transition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can **guarantee** there's a better / more efficient way to do this, and I welcome any suggestions, but here's is how I've done it in the past:

**Initialization:**

```
// No transitions
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  transitionDuration: 0,
  isResizeBound: false
});

// Handle Resize
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('.grid').isotope('layout');
});
```

**Within the filter/click event:**

```
// Add transition & filter 
$('.grid').isotope({
  transitionDuration: '0.4s',
  filter: selector
});

// Remove transition
$('.grid').isotope({
  transitionDuration: 0
});
```

The key is giving `transitionDuration` a value before the filter, and setting it back to `0` after the filter. How you do that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

**First** of all, here is your fiddle,

url: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/so1axnup/18/

**Second**

Here are the two pieces of code which are important in order to achieve such thing:

the property  `isResizeBound: false,` should have the value false (by default it is true) so your elements no more have the transition applied on them.

Here is what the official documentation has to say on that:

> Adjusts sizes and positions when window is resized. Enabled by default
>   isResizeBound: true

The other piece of code is important in order for your elements to **STILL** move when you trigger the resize event.

Here is an example:

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
    isotope.isotope('layout');
  });
});
```

Once you start resizing your window, because of this code, the elements will start to re-position themselves ( you will have that "instant bootstrap effect" and no more "isotope animation effect").

If you decide not to use the "window resize code event", you won't have the element re-positioning occurring (it will sort of gain the effect of an absolute positioned item).

One more thing, be sure to use the V2 isotope js library.

url: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.min.js

**EDIT** as I'm exploring a little bit more, there is also this piece of code which allows you to get your effect

```
 percentPosition: true,
  masonry: {
          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        }
```

see the codepen example: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mIkhq

As I can see, there is a lot more here, but playing with this three things mentioned will definitely get you where you want.

Comment: Setting `isResizeBound: false` without adding `transitionDuration: 0` does **not** remove the animation from the resizing event. Also, the fiddle doesn't seem to work